# Getting error while importing data from MySQL into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to import data from a MySQL database into a SQL Server database. I have created a DSN and am able to successfully connect with the target database. But when I try to import I get the following error in the screen shot:

[image]

Please advise on what am I doing wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TP_Magri_live_stats_1] 
(
    [Dated] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [plateform_base] VARCHAR(255),
    [DefaultProfiles] VARCHAR(255),
    [resubscribers] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubFromOBD] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubFromSMS] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubFromIVR] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubFromUSSD] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubFromWEB] VARCHAR(255),
    [TotalSubs] VARCHAR(255),
    [TotalUnsubs] VARCHAR(255),
    [MornOBDPickupCount] VARCHAR(255),
    [MornOBDConsumedMins] VARCHAR(255),
    [OBDEngUsers] VARCHAR(255),
    [OBDEngMins] VARCHAR(255),
    [HelpRequests] VARCHAR(255),
    [TotalSms] VARCHAR(255),
    [TotalCalls] VARCHAR(255),
    [UniqueCallers] VARCHAR(255),
    [TotalMins] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubTotalCalls] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubUniqueCallers] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubTotalMins] VARCHAR(255),
    [RepeatIntUser] VARCHAR(255),
    [UssdRefCalls] VARCHAR(255),
    [SubCount] VARCHAR(255),
    [UnsubCount] VARCHAR(255),
    [ResubCount] VARCHAR(255),
    [MauUsers] VARCHAR(255),
    [TenDaysUsage] VARCHAR(255),
    [DauUsers] VARCHAR(255),
    [SameDayUnsubs] VARCHAR(255),
    [MonthlyActiveUsers] VARCHAR(255),
    [DauMornOBD] VARCHAR(255),
    [MauMornOBD] VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Comment: post the query!

Comment: Query added to the original question

Comment: Why is everything of type `VARCHAR(255)` - even when the name of column like `SubCount` really seems to indicate it's  **numerical** value?!?!? You should **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype and not just store everything as a string

Comment: Actually this is from a another system...they are just dumping data like that

Comment: So, this has nothing to do with MySQL then; you have a syntax error in a SQL Server query?

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening. I can connect to the remote database, view its data if I am using MySQL Workbench...but when I try to import it in SQL server I get data and cannot preview it

Comment: from the error it seems that you are trying to create the table on MYSQL and not in SQL Server.

Comment: Actually no...my source is mysql and destination is SQL server....I double check when you pointed out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error, you're using a MySQL driver to execute queries on SQL Server.

It could just be the that SQL Server's non SQL-standard compliant use of square brackets around entity names is the problem.

Either:

1. Use a SQL Server driver
2. Don't put square brackets in the output (they are only needed if there are spaces in the entity names, which is a bad idea anyway)

Comment: How do I use an SQL server driver to connect to MySQL...I am using a mysql connector to create a DSN and then using that system level DSN to connect to MySQL database for importing the data in MS SQL Server

Comment: @Amin Baig , It would help if you could add step by step screenshots of what you are doing

Comment: @Amin stating the obvious, use a MySQL driver to connect to MySQL and a SQL Server driver to connect to SQL Server

Comment: Guys...did exactly the same...connecting to the respective databases accordingly but get an error when I try to import.

Comment: @Amin, Please check the following links [MSSQLTIPS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2205/mysql-to-sql-server-data-migration/) and/or [SSMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/getting-started-with-ssma-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-ver15) 
  I have never tried doing this, I do it the hard way MYSQL->Flat Files and then Flat Files->SQL SERVER using SSIS. If the data that you have is huge, split the flat file in chunks